# OCR ID document reader AccessIS OCR315

Tags: ocr

I know that this is very specific question, but ... I have problem with reader OCR315 from company AccessIS on Windows 10 Professional 64x. On Windows 7 Home 86x everything works fine. I'm using reader with ASPS for reading passports with rules and sending data on keyboard. I try to switch logging on and message bellow appears after passport reading :

CHIDInterface::GetDeviceViaInterface - Unable to open device handle (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)

Any ideas, have somebody same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is very likely a permissions conflict or COM port manipulation issue.
Similar to what happens when you try to CHGPORT while a program has an active connection to the device.

Comment: If you need additional information take a look my profile for my email.